# jQuery UI Dialog width not being read from CSS

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I a tried in Chrome and FF.
See the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RY6F5/1/
'width' is not read up by the dialog() instance. 
Same issue with 'height'. However 'color' is read. Any ideas/

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
   <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information.</p>
</div>

#dialog {
  color: red;
  width: 100px;
}

$("#dialog").dialog({
title: 'Information',
    "buttons": [{
    id: 'ok',
    text: "Ok",
    click: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
}]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the width to the js, see code below.
http://jsfiddle.net/RY6F5/1/

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
        title: 'Information',
         width:100, 
            "buttons": [{
            id: 'ok',
            text: "Ok",

            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }]
    });
```

Or with CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/RY6F5/6/

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. I want to be able to use the CSS to edit dialog properties without having to go into the code.

Comment: fiddle works but has downside in that .ui-dialog applies to all dialogs. If you have more than one dialog, well you back to square 1.

Comment: Specify with :nth-child(x)

Answer (score 0):

Well I have an answer. It can be done by adding the width: parameter but fetching the width from the CSS of the id:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    width: parseInt($('#dialog').css('width')), // Convert to integer to remove px
    title: 'Information',
        "buttons": [{
        id: 'ok',
        text: "Ok",
        click: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }]
});
```